# thinking sphinx hitting errors in indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

With a migration of sphinx to 2.2.6 and thinking-sphinx to 3.1.2, rails 3.2.18 and

```
require 'thinking_sphinx/capistrano'
```

included in the capfile, thinking-sphinx does not appear to launch

Manually,

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake ts:configure
```

generates the conf file
  Indexing hits some warnings. `max_matches` and `enable_star` were removed from the YAML file and don't reappear.  But then a string of warnings about `sql_query_info` and `charset_type` are popping up and I have no clue where to fix.  Then this follows:

```
indexing index 'document_core'...
WARNING: word overrun buffer, clipped!!!
clipped (len=126, word='�')
original (len=128, word='')
```

Leading to the index files not being created.

P.S.  I added the jdbc gem, based on release notes, although I don't use it.  But system warns `Jdbc-MySQL is only for use with JRuby`.  Better to remove?

Comment: You only need jdbc and its related gems if you're using JRuby - so, if you're not doing that, it can definitely be removed. But I think this is unrelated to the error you're seeing (which I've not come across before).

Comment: You can ignore the warnings about sql_query_info and charset_type though - they won't stop things from working. Just to confirm, is there an ERROR or FATAL in the output? Or just this WARNING about the word overrun buffer?

Comment: It is just a warning.  And, oh now, `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake ts:start` runs (I call this the 'why-not-the-first-time-ghost').  Still, getting newfangled errors, which don't jive.  `Using the old-fashion @variables (@count, @weight, etc.) is deprecated - SELECT * FROM `azienda_core` WHERE MATCH('prova') AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 ORDER BY @weight DESC LIMIT 0, 75; SHOW META` complains about `<%= @results.count %>` where index is defined as `ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :azienda, :with => :active_record do
  indexes attivita indexes prodotti indexes ragione_sociale indexes comune`

Comment: there is no @weight invoked in any particular place I can think of...

Comment: Is this app using TS v3.1.x?

Comment: Yup.  3.1.2  I updated ts (& sphinx) given compatibility with capistrano

Comment: Okay - if you followed the release notes with modifications to TS to use Sphinx 2.1.x (covered in https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/releases/tag/v3.0.6) or Sphinx 2.0.x (covered in https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/releases/tag/v3.1.0), you need to remove those. Also, can you confirm in a project-wide search you're not using `@weight` anywhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65185/discussion-between-jerome-and-pat).